# How can I use AJAX as an alternative to an iframe?

Tags: php, ajax, iframe

at the moment I am using iframes on my website to display content from other pages like forms. The problem I have, is on the login page, when the user logs in with a form inside an iframe, it just shows the next page inside the login iframe - which is completely useless.

I have heard that AJAX is much more flexible and dynamic for things like this, but I can't work out how to use it, I have looked at some tutorials but don't seem to be getting that far in displaying a page inside a page.

How can I replace my iframe with AJAX?

Thank in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you won't be using iFrames you will need a container to put your page into. With AJAX, it is common practice to use a `<div>` element to hold that data. Also, jQuery or another Javascript library supporting AJAX will make your life easier with working tested code so you can focus on your business logic rather than the nitty gritty. So, in your HTML, you will need a container element:

```
<div id="otherpage"></div>
```

Then in an included javascript file, you can use this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#otherpage').load('otherpage.html', function() {
      alert('Load was performed.');
   });
});
```

Of course, before using that, make sure you include jQuery as well. [This tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery) should help you get started with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I was trying to do, and explained really clearly. thank you :) x

Comment: I just found this and thought it would be just the thing to replace some iframes. I copied the code into my page and Bang! It worked perfectly first time.
Then I tried to click on a button in my 'otherpage' and it didn't work. That button also operates a bit of jQuery. Am I trying to do the impossible? Or is it just a trivial little issue I'm missing?

Comment: Just now seeing this comment 4 years later because somebody upvoted. To answer for future readers, when you load HTML content dynamically, you need to make sure your jquery bindings are on the document, not on the element. For example: `$(document).on('click', '.my-button', myHandler);` instead of `$('.my-button').on('click', myHandler);`

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is more related to ajax than any other thing.

Try to "pre-load" your js functions in the host html (not the one loaded via ajax) and just load the specific rendering html through ajax.

Then, use jquery ".done( function(data) { ... " method to invoque js functions you "pre-loaded" << (included in the base html/document) once they are ready to go.

Hope this help, Regards.

Try something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax(
            url    : './your_script.php',
            context: 'document',
        ).done(function(data){
            $('#your_div').html( data );
            your_js_function();
        })
    });

    // ---- main html
    function your_js_function(){
        alert('got it!');
    };
```