# How can I JQuery onClick specific links to display pages in a Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Going off of this page's answer:
[How can I use AJAX as an alternative to an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371801/how-can-i-use-ajax-as-an-alternative-to-an-iframe)

I'm trying to make multiple links in one div "feedwrap" AJAX their destinations into another div on the page "Content"

I'm wondering if there's anyway to make all the links standard but use JQuery to automatically make each one open in the new div.. or have an onClick script on each link that opens it in the other div, if necessary.

Here's an idea.. I'm rather sure it doesn't work this way, haha.

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#content').load('otherpage.html');" 
class="link-title">link text</a>
```

But if there could be one script to rule them all, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() { 
$(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) { 
$('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Comment: This kind of works, like if I leave the href="#" it will open a copy of the page in the div...  but if I make it point to an actual page, it just opens the page in the parent window.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.link-title').click(function(){$('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));})
```