# redirecting parent page after session expires C#

Tags: c#, redirect, iframe, httpcontext, response.redirect

I am working on a piece of code that directly relates to redirecting a page to a login screen if the user id is non existent.

The code is currently written as:

```
this.currentContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
this.User = new BLL.User(); // base constructor
this.User.RestoreSession(currentContext.Session); // attempt to connect to DB with current session

if (this.UserID < 1)
{
    currentContext.Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx?url=" + currentContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToBase64());
}
```

Which work's just fine.

However in a new addon we are building into the system it uses iframes which is okay but the login screen happens in the iframe and we need to make the parent window redirect to the login window then redirect back to page we were on.

My question is what would be the best way of doing this without rewriting the entire login process?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do redirect without rewriting the login process is to replace iframes with Ajax calls. Check this: [How can I use AJAX as an alternative to an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371801/how-can-i-use-ajax-as-an-alternative-to-an-iframe)